# I want to merge my PhD Research Proposal code with pgfgantt, wrap text in label

Tags: pgfgantt, charts

I want to merge my PhD Research Proposal code with `pgfgantt` and wrap the text in a label.

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 %%pgf gantt, wrap text in label
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{indentfirst}
 \usepackage{pgf}
 \usepackage{pgfgantt}
 \usepackage{pgfcalendar}
 \usepackage{rotating}
 \usepackage[filename=tasktips,mouseover,noextratext]{fancytooltips}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 \usepackage{amscd}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{epsfig}
 \usepackage{verbatim}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \pagestyle{empty}
 \usepackage{color}
 %\usepackage[all,dvips]{xy}
 \newcommand{\sign}[1]{%
 \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
 \makebox[1.5in]{\dotfill}\\
 \strut#1\strut
 \end{tabular}%
 }
 \newcommand{\Date}{%
 \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{1.5in}@{}}
 \\[-2ex]
 \strut Date: \dotfill\strut
 \end{tabular}%
 }

 \setlength{\textheight}{8.5in} \setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in}
 \setlength{\headheight}{0.0in} \setlength{\headsep}{0.0in}
 \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.5in}
 \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
 %\setlength{\parindent}{1pc}
 \setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
 %\linespread{1.6}

 \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
 \newtheorem{problem}{Problem}

 \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
 \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
 \newtheorem{note}[theorem]{Note}
 \newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
 \newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposition}

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 \begin{document}
 \thispagestyle{empty}

 \bigskip
 \bigskip

 \centerline{\textbf{\Large{Research Proposal}}}

 \bigskip
 \bigskip


 \noindent \textbf{Name:} %Your name goes here.

 \bigskip

 \noindent \textbf{Field of the Project:} %Write your majors, minors or GECs.

 \bigskip

 \noindent \textbf{Project Title:} %Write a brief description of the topic you wish to work on. This should be done in 40 words or less.

 \bigskip

 \noindent\textbf{Abstract of the Project:} %Remove the comment (percentage) symbol in front of the appropriate category:


 %double with another major.

 \bigskip

 \noindent\textbf{State of the Art:}%Remove the comment (percentage) symbol in front of the appropriate category:



 \bigskip

 \noindent \textbf{Description of the Project:} %Write the name of any professor(s) you think you might want to work with on this topic. You may leave this section blank if you don't know.

 \bigskip

 \noindent \textbf{Expected results and practical/technical/commercial outcomes:}
 %List the courses which are relevant; you don't need to list every mathematics course you have ever taken.

 \bigskip

 \begin{thebibliography}{99}

 \end{thebibliography}

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 %%pgf gantt, wrap text in label
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \pagebreak
 \begin{rotate}{270}
 \begin{ganttchart}[y unit title=0.6cm,
  y unit chart=0.7cm,
  vgrid,
  title height=.85,
  hgrid=true,
  canvas/.style={fill=yellow!25, draw=blue, solid, very thick},
  bar/.style={fill=gray, rounded corners=3pt},
  bar left shift=.05,
  bar right shift=-.05,
  bar top shift=.3,
  bar height=.3,vgrid={*1{blue, dashed}},
  bar label font=\normalsize\color{black!50},
  bar label anchor/.append style={align=left, text width=1.5cm},
  group right shift=0,group top shift=.6,group height=.3,group peaks={}{}  {0}]{23}
 \gantttitle{2012}{5}
 \gantttitle{2013}{12}
 \gantttitle{2014}{6}\\
 \gantttitlelist{8,...,12}{1}
 \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1}
 \gantttitlelist{1,...,6}{1}\\


 \ganttgroup{\tooltip{Objective 1}{obje1}}{1}{4} \\
 \ganttbar{\tooltip{\textbf{Task a}}{task1a}}{4}{2} \\
 \ganttbar{\textbf{Task b}}{4}{2} \\
 \ganttbar{\textbf{Task c}}{4}{2} \\

 \ganttgroup{Objective 2:}{4}{6} \\
 \ganttbar{Task a}{4}{6} \\
 \ganttbar{Task b}{4}{6} \\

 \ganttgroup{Objective 3}{4}{6} \\
 \ganttbar{Task a}{4}{2} \\
 \ganttbar{Task b}{4}{2} \\
 \ganttbar{Task c}{4}{2} \\
 \ganttbar{Task d}{4}{2} \\

 \ganttgroup{Objective 4}{4}{6} \\
 \ganttbar{Task a}{4}{2} \\
 \ganttbar{Task b}{4}{2} \\

 \ganttgroup{Objective 5}{4}{6} \\
 \ganttbar{Task a}{4}{2} \\
 \ganttbar{Task b}{4}{2} \\
 \ganttbar{Task c}{4}{2} \\

 \end{ganttchart}

 \end{rotate}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


 \end{document}
```

Related Questions:

- [pgfgantt, wrap text in label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66077/pgfgantt-wrap-text-in-label/66097?noredirect=1#comment619444_66097)
- [Adjust width of a gantt chart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253253/how-to-make-research-proposal-including-a-timeframe?noredirect=1#comment619420_253253)

Comment: You're question is too broad to be answered. Be more specific and provide an example.

Comment: Add the code that generates the gantt chart just before `\end{document}` of your research proposal.

Comment: @Johannes_B  Package hyperref Error: Wrong driver option "pdftex"
(hyperref)                      because pdfTeX in PDF mode is not detected.

Comment: What is your OS ? Did you installed `PDFTeX` ?

Comment: Neither this question, nor the two linked question/answers nor the code posted on LC are showing any sign of `pdftex`. So far, the question is perfectly clear for you, but completely unclear for us.

Comment: There are many language specific communities around the world. It think the problem at hand is basicallydue to language problems. Please have a look at the list: https://www.tug.org/usergroups.html

Comment: This is probably a full duplicate of [How to make research proposal including a timeframe?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/253253)?

Comment: @RémiBecheras WinEdt with LaTeX

Comment: @Johannes_B yeap

Answer (score 1):

### This is not an answer

Once you've generated the tooltips as explained in the answer you linked to, please process the following document, **without modifications** (i.e., opean a brand new file, copy-paste the code below *as is*):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\usepackage[filename=tasktips,mouseover,noextratext]{fancytooltips}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{ganttchart}[y unit title=0.6cm,
  y unit chart=0.7cm,
  vgrid,
  title height=.85,
  hgrid=true,
  canvas/.style={fill=yellow!25, draw=blue, solid, very thick},
  bar/.style={fill=gray, rounded corners=3pt},
  bar left shift=.05,
  bar right shift=-.05,
  bar top shift=.3,
  bar height=.3,vgrid={*1{blue, dashed}},
  bar label font=\normalsize\color{black!50},
  bar label anchor/.append style={align=left, text width=1.5cm},
  group right shift=0,group top shift=.6,group height=.3,group peaks height=.4]{1}{23}
 \gantttitle{2012}{5}
 \gantttitle{2013}{12}
 \gantttitle{2014}{6}\\
 \gantttitlelist{8,...,12}{1}
 \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1}
 \gantttitlelist{1,...,6}{1}\\


 \ganttgroup{\tooltip{Objective 1}{obje1}}{1}{4} \\
 \ganttbar{\tooltip{\textbf{Task a}}{task1a}}{4}{2} \\
 \ganttbar{\textbf{Task b}}{4}{2} \\
 \ganttbar{\textbf{Task c}}{4}{2} \\

 \ganttgroup{Objective 2:}{4}{6} \\
 \ganttbar{Task a}{4}{6} \\
 \ganttbar{Task b}{4}{6} \\

 \ganttgroup{Objective 3}{4}{6} \\
 \ganttbar{Task a}{4}{2} \\
 \ganttbar{Task b}{4}{2} \\
 \ganttbar{Task c}{4}{2} \\
 \ganttbar{Task d}{4}{2} \\

 \ganttgroup{Objective 4}{4}{6} \\
 \ganttbar{Task a}{4}{2} \\
 \ganttbar{Task b}{4}{2} \\

 \ganttgroup{Objective 5}{4}{6} \\
 \ganttbar{Task a}{4}{2} \\
 \ganttbar{Task b}{4}{2} \\
 \ganttbar{Task c}{4}{2} \\

 \end{ganttchart}

 \end{document}
```

Please report the result.

Comment: Package hyperref Error: Wrong driver option "pdftex" (hyperref) because pdfTeX in PDF mode is not detected.

Comment: @MickyK Please process the document with `pdflatex`, not with `latex`; since fancytooltips are being used, processing with `latex` will trigger errors.

Comment: PDFLaTeX failed to create a pdf file